# Como converter uma string em booleano?

Tags: javascript, conversão-de-tipo

No JavaScript, ao executar

```
Boolean('false')
```

O valor retornado é `true` e o esperado era `false`, vez que strings com qualquer conteúdo não vazio ao serem convertidas para booleano retornam `true` e as vazias `false`.

Qual é a **melhor forma** de converter uma string para um booleano no JavaScript?

Comment: Que tipo de conteúdo queres converter? `Boolean()` funciona bem e é semanticamente correto.

Comment: Sim, ao meu ver essa é a melhor forma: `Boolean(string)`.

Comment: @vnbrs queres que `Boolean('false')` dê `false`? queres saber como detectar `false` dentro de uma string? é essa a pergunta?

Comment: `var convertido = 'false' == 'true';`

Comment: Mas está muito confuso. Você mesmo diz que qualquer string não vazia é considerada `true`, mas afirma que `Boolean("false")` seria esperado `false`. Isso não faz sentido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare a *string* que você quer validar com `true`:

```
var texto = 'false';
var valBool = texto.toLowerCase() == 'true';
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var varbool = Boolean('false'=='true');
alert(varbool);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Possível, mas não recomendável

Se você precisa converter diretamente pode usar a função `eval()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval.

No seu caso poderia fazer:

```
const parseBool = value => eval(value)
```

Esse código é bem inseguro, pois fiz nenhuma checagem pra saber `value` é true ou false (como string), mas assim `parsedValue` vai ter um valor booleano. Há problemas de seguranças envolvidos, pois eval, dependendo da forma e propósito com a qual é utilizado, pode abrir brechas para [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) na sua aplicação.

## Recomendável

Creio que a melhor solução seja utilizar comparação como já citado:

```
const parseBool = value => 
      ['true', 'false'].includes(value) ? value === true : null
```

Esse exemplo acompanha uma pequena checagem apenas para ilustrar o fato de que você pode retornar `null` ou qualquer outro valor para identificar que o valor passado é inválido ou algo do tipo, mas não é obrigatório.

Comment: A resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235274/80474 é muito mais simples. Tanto o eval quanto o método `includes` adicionam um overhead dispensável ao código (além de o `includes` ter um alcance de uso muito limitado como expresso aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains)

Comment: Eu que não fui claro quando disse que o `includes` foi apenas uma forma de exemplificar que ele poderia fazer uma checagem e que o eval era não recomendado, mas sempre vale o conhecimento ou você que não leu tudo o que escrevi? E ainda, eu fiz questão de dizer que o exemplo usando comparação já havia sido citado antes.

Comment: @stefanosanders Queria retirar o down vote, como faço? Você precisa editar a sua resposta, é isso?

Comment: Ih rapaz, ai eu não sei, acho que nesse caso nem `eval` nem `includes` vão resolver rs :P